# Need help IntentService not starting

Tags: android-intentservice

After unsuccessful attempts to find what is the problem with my IntentService, (reading and googling) I decide to ask at stakeoverflow. I couldn't figure our what is wrong with this code. I actually want to start a service after receiving result from another activity. I do get result from that activity then comes to the method from where i want to start this service.

Service Starter Code

```
Intent templateCreationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TemplateCreationService.class);
    templateCreationIntent.putExtra(TemplateCreationService.PARAM_IN_MSG,userName);
    startService(templateCreationIntent);
```

Service Code

```
public class TemplateCreationService extends IntentService{

private static final String TAG = "TemplateCreationService";
public static final int STATUS_RUNNING = 0;
public static final int STATUS_FINISHED = 1;
public static final int STATUS_ERROR = 2;


static final String TEST_RAW_DATA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/gaitDataRecording"+ "/rawTestingData" + "/acc/";
public static String userName;
public static String cycleLength;
public static final String PARAM_OUT_MSG = "omsg";
public static final String PARAM_IN_MSG = "imsg";

public TemplateCreationService() {
    super(TemplateCreationService.class.getName());
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG,"Template Creation Service Started");
    userName = intent.getStringExtra(PARAM_IN_MSG);

    try {
        Boolean b = DataProcessingStepsV2.gaitDataLoading(TRAIN_RAW_DATA_PATH, userName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    double []gaitCycleLengths = DataProcessingStepsV2.getCycleLengths();

    cycleLength = gaitCycleLengths.toString();

    // processing done here….
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction(ResponseReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
    broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    broadcastIntent.putExtra(PARAM_OUT_MSG,cycleLength);
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent); 
    }    
  }
```

Manifest

```
<service   android:name=".gait_authentication_segmentation.TemplateCreationService"
    android:exported = "false"/>
```

Main Activity Registering Receiver

```
 IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ResponseReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
 filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
 receiver = new ResponseReceiver();
 registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Broadcast Receiver

```
public class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
       public static final String ACTION_RESP =    
          "at.usmile.gait_authentication.intent.action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED";

       @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), intent.getStringExtra(TemplateCreationService.PARAM_OUT_MSG),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           //String text = intent.getStringExtra(SimpleIntentService.PARAM_OUT_MSG);
           //result.setText(text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it going in onHandleIntent of Intentservice?

Comment: I tried to debug but its not going to onHandleIntent(Intent intent) method

Comment: check the service declaration in manifest.xml i.e is the name correct and is it the fully qualified name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the name of Service in the AndroidManifest.xml is not correct. It can be:

1. It is not the fully qualified name.
2. There is some spelling mistake.

Try giving full package name with the service name and give it a try.

Comment: Thanks alot, you are right it was problem with service name in AndroidManifest.xml, When I try with full package name it starts the service. So what I understood, that if we have service.java in some package other than containing activities we must use full package name with the service else we can use .ServiceName in AndroidManifest.XML

Comment: No we can give a relative path as well for the service class but the name in the package of manifest tag at the top + the name you entered in the name of service should make a fully qualified name. For e.g if the service lies in package com.example.android.service that manifest tag contains package = "com.example.android" and service tag contains name=".service.YourServiceName" that when added gives com.example.android.service.YourServiceName. If still in doubt please mention.